# MouseDragged and MouseMoved not fired on javafx if button has been released

Tags: java, button, mouseevent, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to have a pan / zoom  mouse manipulation of my node in javafx

The behavior shall be as in CATIA V5 for those who knows it:
- press the middle button, you will be "PANNING" and the view will follow your moves
- keep the middle button pressed, press the third button, you will be "ROTATING" (not used here, useful in 3D)
- keep the middle button pressed, release the third button, you will be "ZOOMING" and the view will zoom in and out when you move up and down

Unfortunately, it seems javafx does not fire anymore MouseDragged or MouveMoved once I entered the ZOOMING state.

As if the third button release had an effect on the events fired.

Here is my code:
the zooming functions affect "contentGroup" in my "ViewTab"
a small state "manipulationState" ensure the switches between behaviors

I can enter ZOOM state, but on mouse move, neither `onMouseDragged` or `onMouseMoved` are called. 
as a consequence `moveZoom()` is never called.

Is there a way to get an event on mousemove ? Thanks for your help.

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;


public class ViewTab extends Tab {

    private final double ZOOMFACTOR = 1;
    double contentGroupScale = 1.0;
    double pressedContentGroupScale;
    private double pressedX, pressedY, initialX, initialY;
    private Group contentGroup;

    private enum ManipulationState {

        IDLE, PAN, ROTATE, ZOOM
    }
    private ManipulationState manipulationState;

    ViewTab() {
        TitleNode rootNode = Tools.loadTree();
        //create view
        AbstractView rootView = OakweaverPresenterFactory.createView(rootNode, null);
        setText("Tree");
        contentGroup = new Group();
        contentGroup.getChildren().add(rootView);
        createZoomFunctions();

        setContent(contentGroup);
    }

    public void createZoomFunctions() {
        enterIdle();
        contentGroup.setScaleX(contentGroupScale);
        contentGroup.setScaleY(contentGroupScale);

        contentGroup.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                switch (manipulationState) {
                    case IDLE:
                        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
                            enterPan(event);
                        }
                        break;
                    case PAN:
                        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                            enterRotate(event);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ROTATE:

                        break;
                    case ZOOM:
                        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                            enterRotate(event);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        contentGroup.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                switch (manipulationState) {
                    case IDLE:

                        break;
                    case PAN:
                        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
                            enterIdle();
                        }

                        break;
                    case ROTATE:
                        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
                            enterIdle();
                        }
                        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                            enterZoom(event);
                        }
                        break;
                    case ZOOM:
                        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
                            enterIdle();
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

        contentGroup.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("draged");

                switch (manipulationState) {
                    case IDLE:
                        break;
                    case PAN:
                        movePan(event);
                        break;
                    case ROTATE:
                        moveRotate(event);
                        break;
                    case ZOOM:
                        moveZoom(event);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        //note: javafx does not fire anymore mousemoved or mousedragged when we have made a "zooming" manipulation with the buttons
        contentGroup.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("moved");

                switch (manipulationState) {
                    case IDLE:
                        break;
                    case PAN:
                        movePan(event);
                        break;
                    case ROTATE:
                        moveRotate(event);
                        break;
                    case ZOOM:
                        moveZoom(event);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        contentGroup.setMouseTransparent(
                false);
    }

    public void enterIdle() {
        manipulationState = ManipulationState.IDLE;
        contentGroup.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

        System.out.println(manipulationState);

    }

    public void enterPan(MouseEvent event) {

        manipulationState = ManipulationState.PAN;
        pressedX = event.getSceneX();
        pressedY = event.getSceneY();
        initialX = contentGroup.getTranslateX();
        initialY = contentGroup.getTranslateY();
        contentGroup.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        System.out.println(manipulationState);

    }

    public void enterRotate(MouseEvent event) {
        manipulationState = ManipulationState.ROTATE;
        contentGroup.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println(manipulationState);
    }

    public void enterZoom(MouseEvent event) {
        manipulationState = ManipulationState.ZOOM;
        pressedX = event.getSceneX();
        pressedY = event.getSceneY();
        initialX = contentGroup.getTranslateX();
        initialY = contentGroup.getTranslateY();
        pressedContentGroupScale = contentGroupScale;

        contentGroup.setCursor(Cursor.V_RESIZE);
        System.out.println(manipulationState);

    }

    public void movePan(MouseEvent event) {
        contentGroup.setTranslateX(initialX + (event.getSceneX() - pressedX));
        contentGroup.setTranslateY(initialY + (event.getSceneY() - pressedY));
    }

    public void moveRotate(MouseEvent event) {
    }

    public void moveZoom(MouseEvent event) {
        contentGroupScale = pressedContentGroupScale * Math.exp(ZOOMFACTOR * (event.getSceneY() - pressedY));

        contentGroup.setScaleX(contentGroupScale);
        contentGroup.setScaleY(contentGroupScale);
    }
}
```